# Advice on how to organize controllers asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

learning mvc and building a full blown ecommerce app.

Administrators should be able to add-edit whatever they like.

Let's take an example Employees.

I have added an Area called "Admin".Within admin I have Employees
In here an administrator should be able to add-edit info about employees.

Now in the user section the user should not be able to add-edit.etc..

At them moment I have 2 controllers?

1. Areas-Admin-Controllers-EmployeeController
2. Areas-Aboutus-Controllers-EmployeeController

It does not seem right to me.How do you handle such a code repetition?
I would like to have only one controller.How do you structure your mvc app in this case?

any example I can download?
Looking for a good examples where you can see areas working and running themes dynamically etc..

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single `~/Controllers/EmployeesController` controller to handle the `Employee` resource in your application. Inside this controller actions that require administrative (or some logged in user) privileges could be decorated with the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute by specifying the required roles in order to execute this action:

```
public class EmployeesController: Controller
{
    // Anyone can list employees, even anonymous users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> employees = _repository.GetEmployees();
        return View(employees);
    }

    public ActionResult Show(int employeeId)
    {
        Employee employee = _repository.GetEmployee(employeeId);
        return View(employee);
    }


    // Only administrators can update employees
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(Employee employee)
    {
        _repository.Update(employee);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Only administrators can delete employees
    [HttpDelete]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult Destroy(int employeeId)
    {
        _repository.Delete(employeeId);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ... and some other actions following the Simply RESTful pattern: 
    http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Do you mean create EmployeeController in the main controllers NOT in areas and then put an authorize attribute on the methods that require admin.Is this what you mean? Also Can you you hide "Add-Edit-Delete" in the view if not adminRole. When viewing the list i want to hide the above links if not admin.Is there an @If AdminRole{etc..}

Comment: @user231465, yes that's exactly what I mean. As far as hiding of the links is concerned that's totally possible. You could define on your view models boolean properties indicating whether some link should be shown and inside your controller action aliment this property by `User.IsInRole("admin")`. I've seen people doing directly `@if (User.IsInRole("admin")) { ... }` in their views but personally I prefer doing this in the controller and pass the information to the view in the view model. So inside the view: `@if (Model.ShouldShowSomeLinks) { ... }`

Comment: ... Another technique I like about conditionally showing some links based on user roles is to write custom ActionLink helpers which check the roles of the currently logged in user and if the user is in role I delegate to the standard ActionLink helper and if not I simply return an empty string.

Comment: grateful for your time. I have just created an "EmployeeController" in Controllers. All good ,forgive my naive question now how do I redirect to Areas-Aboutus-Views-Employee-Index (not Admin section) or to Areas-Admin-Views-Employee-Index(Admin section) . I have seen you use redirecttoaction(Actionname?)but not sure i can go to either of them

Comment: @user231465, if the EmployeesController is not in the areas it means that its views should also respect those conventions. Why do you want to redirect to `Areas-Aboutus-Views-Employee-Index` and from where?

Comment: Because of the "area" concept i have 2 areas "Aboutus" and "Admin" and they both need an employee-index view.I dont want to scrap the area concept.It seems a good one to me. I have 2 Employee Index views one in aboutus and one in admin .They both use a partial "EmployeeList"view.If a remove the views from the areas there will be nothing there

Answer (score 1):

I'm assumuing your doing it this way so that you can use authentication and have the pretty urls:
/Admin/Employee
/Aboutus/Employee

How about only having a single controller in /Controllers/EmployeeController. You can set [Authorize] attribute on any methods that you need authentication for and control the urls with custom routes?

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Admin_Employee", _
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Employee", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )

    routes.MapRoute( _
        "AboutUs_Employee", _
        "Aboutus/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Employee", .action = "Details", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am doing this way because of good urls but also because as of my knowledge at this minute it seemed a good way todo it,willing to change if it does not make sense.Just wondering how people do it

Comment: You can checkout the 'The Beer House' sample project on codeplex. It has some good examples of how to do this. http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com

Comment: Trying to understand you suggested routing.I can see the difference but not sure how it works.Are you saying it will find the employeecontroller regardless where I am going because of your routing?

Comment: Exactly. The routing translates the url to the actual code that runs.

Comment: In my main Controller "EmployeeController.Index" Return View is now not pointing to anything.To what should it be pointing?The idea is it should redirect accordingly.but how?